# Java Threads not working correctly with JTextArea

Tags: java, string, multithreading, jtextarea

In Java, I am creating a login/register program at the moment (hoping to expand it in the future) but have run into a problem.

I am trying to make text appear across the screen in an animated type writer styled fashion.

When I run the class's main method, the text appears just fine, when I run it in a keylistener, it fails and waits for text to appear, THEN updates the frame so I can see it.

Source Code Below:

**Login.class**

```
public class Login implements KeyListener {

int BACK_WIDTH = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
int BACK_HEIGHT = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

JFrame back_frame = new JFrame();

LoginTerminal login = new LoginTerminal();

public Login() {
    back_frame.setSize(BACK_WIDTH, BACK_HEIGHT);
    back_frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    back_frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    back_frame.setUndecorated(true);
    //back_frame.setVisible(true);

    back_frame.addKeyListener(this);
    login.addKeyListener(this);
    login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    login.setVisible(true);
    login.field.addKeyListener(this);

    login.slowPrint("Please login to continue...\n"
               + "Type 'help' for more information.\n");
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getKeyCode();

    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        login.slowPrint("\nCommands\n"
                 + "-----------\n"
                 + "register\n"
                 + "login\n");
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

**LoginTerminal.class**

```
public class LoginTerminal implements KeyListener {

CustomFrame frame = new CustomFrame(Types.TERMINAL);

JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
public JTextField field = new JTextField();

public void setVisible(boolean bool) {
    frame.setVisible(bool);
}

public void addKeyListener(KeyListener listener) {
    frame.addKeyListener(listener);
}

public void slowPrint(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        log.append("" + str.charAt(i));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (i == str.length() - 1) {
            log.append("\n");
        }
    }
}

public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}

public void setLocationRelativeTo(Component c) {
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(c);
}

public LoginTerminal() {
    try {

        InputStream is = LoginTerminal.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/dungeon.TTF");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 10);

        frame.add(field);
        frame.add(log);

        log.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        log.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        log.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        log.setLineWrap(true);
        log.setBounds(4, 20 + 4, frame.getWidth() - 8, frame.getHeight() - 50);
        log.setFont(font);
        log.setEditable(false);
        log.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);

        field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        field.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        field.setBounds(2, frame.getHeight() - 23, frame.getWidth() - 5, 20);
        field.setFont(font);
        field.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);
        field.addKeyListener(this);
        field.setText("  >  ");

    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void dumpToLog() {
    log.append(field.getText() + "\n");
    field.setText("  >  ");
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getKeyCode();

    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && field.isFocusOwner()) {
        if(field.getText().equals("  >  HELP") || field.getText().equals("  >  help")) {
            dumpToLog();


        } else {
            dumpToLog();
        }
    }


    if(!field.getText().startsWith("  >  ")) {
        field.setText("  >  ");
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

**Main.class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Login();
    }

}
```

My problem is here:

```
public Login() {
    login.slowPrint("Please login to continue...\n"
               + "Type 'help' for more information.\n");
}
```

When, I run that, it works as expected.

Whereas below in the same class (Login.class)

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getKeyCode();

    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        login.slowPrint("\nCommands\n"
                 + "-----------\n"
                 + "register\n"
                 + "login\n");
    }
}
```

It freezes and waits for finish.

I think it may be the Thread.sleep(50); in LoginTerminal.class as the title states due to the fact that that is what triggers the typing animation.

Hope I made myself clear here.
Thanks for the help all!

**EDIT**

This is what causes the Timer error...

```
public void timerPrint(String text) {
Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (index < text.length() - 1 && index >= 0) {
            String newChar = Character.toString(text.charAt(index));
            textArea.append(newChar);
            index++;
        } else {
            textArea.setText(null);
            index = 0;
           // You could stop the timer here...
        }
   }
});
timer.start();
}
```

**The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined**

**EDIT EDIT, Whole class:**

```
package com.finn.frametypes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import com.finn.gui.CustomFrame;
import com.finn.gui.Types;

public class LoginTerminal implements KeyListener {

CustomFrame frame = new CustomFrame(Types.TERMINAL);

JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
public JTextField field = new JTextField();

public void setVisible(boolean bool) {
    frame.setVisible(bool);
}

public void addKeyListener(KeyListener listener) {
    frame.addKeyListener(listener);
}
public void timerPrint(String text) {
Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (index < text.length() - 1 && index >= 0) {
            String newChar = Character.toString(text.charAt(index));
            textArea.append(newChar);
            index++;
        } else {
            textArea.setText(null);
            index = 0;
           // You could stop the timer here...
        }
   }
});
timer.start();
}

public void slowPrint(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        log.append("" + str.charAt(i));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (i == str.length() - 1) {
            log.append("\n");
        }
    }
}

public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}

public void setLocationRelativeTo(Component c) {
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(c);
}

public LoginTerminal() {
    try {

        InputStream is = LoginTerminal.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/dungeon.TTF");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 10);

        frame.add(field);
        frame.add(log);

        log.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        log.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        log.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        log.setLineWrap(true);
        log.setBounds(4, 20 + 4, frame.getWidth() - 8, frame.getHeight() - 50);
        log.setFont(font);
        log.setEditable(false);
        log.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);

        field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        field.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        field.setBounds(2, frame.getHeight() - 23, frame.getWidth() - 5, 20);
        field.setFont(font);
        field.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);
        field.addKeyListener(this);
        field.setText("  >  ");

    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void dumpToLog() {
    log.append(field.getText() + "\n");
    field.setText("  >  ");
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getKeyCode();

    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && field.isFocusOwner()) {
        if(field.getText().equals("  >  HELP") || field.getText().equals("  >  help")) {
            dumpToLog();


        } else {
            dumpToLog();
        }
    }


    if(!field.getText().startsWith("  >  ")) {
        field.setText("  >  ");
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

**ANSWER**

If anyone reads this in the future and wants to use slowprinting in Java, use the below:

```
int index;

public void timerPrint(final String text) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (index < text.length() - 1 && index >= 0) {
                String newChar = Character.toString(text.charAt(index));
                textarea.append(newChar);
                index++;
            } else {
                index = 0;
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
       }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any thread-related code.

Comment: Thread.sleep(50); Im assuming thats the problem as it freezes. I will make post more clear.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` is actually not related to threads.

Comment: Well what is it related to? (noob question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework, that is, anything that blocks the Event Dispatching Thread will prevent the UI from been updated or for your program to respond to new threads

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

You should never perform any blocking (`Thread.sleep`) or long running processes from within the EDT.

Swing is also NOT thread safe, this means, that you should never update the UI from outside the context of the EDT.

This leaves you in a conundrum...

Luckily, there are options.  Probably the simplest solution for your case is to use a Swing `Timer`, which can be used to schedule a regular callback into the EDT, where you can perform updates

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

For example...

[image: Scrolling Text]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ScrollingText100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollingText100();
    }

    public ScrollingText100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String text;
        private int index;
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public TestPane() {            
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            textArea = new JTextArea(2, 40);
            add(textArea);

            text = "Please login to continue...\n" + "Type 'help' for more information.\n";
            Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (index < text.length() - 1 && index >= 0) {
                        String newChar = Character.toString(text.charAt(index));
                        textArea.append(newChar);
                        index++;
                    } else {
                        textArea.setText(null);
                        index = 0;
                        // You could stop the timer here...
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated**

If I understand your requirements properly, something like this...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LoginTerminal {

    private JTextArea log = new JTextArea(20, 40);
    private JTextField field = new JTextField();

    private int index;
    private StringBuilder textToDisplay;
    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginTerminal();
    }

    public LoginTerminal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                textToDisplay = new StringBuilder(128);
                timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (textToDisplay.length() > 0) {
                            String newChar = Character.toString(textToDisplay.charAt(0));
                            textToDisplay.delete(0, 1);
                            log.append(newChar);
                        } else {
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(log));

                log.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                log.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                log.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                log.setLineWrap(true);
                log.setEditable(false);
                log.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);

                field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                field.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                field.setCaretColor(Color.BLACK);
                field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if ("  >  HELP".equalsIgnoreCase(field.getText())) {
                            dumpToLog();
                        } else {
                            dumpToLog();
                        }
                    }
                });
                field.setText("  >  ");

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void timerPrint(String text) {

        textToDisplay.append(text).append("\n");
        if (!timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public void slowPrint(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            log.append("" + str.charAt(i));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == str.length() - 1) {
                log.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void dumpToLog() {
        timerPrint(field.getText());
    }

}
```

may be what you're actually look for.

Note, `KeyListener`s aren't a good choice for `JTextComponent`s, in this case an `ActionListener` is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way that I can also be able to add text to it? Like.... I input my text in a JTextField like in my example and it gives an output when I press Enter/Return, because when I output, that is the problem as it will not slow write like what you have given me. Hope you understand!

Comment: Conceptually, you can do anything.  In the example, `text` is used by the `Timer`, so you should be able to supply that variable with what ever you want.  I would, however, `stop` the `Timer` first, reset the `index` value and then `restart` the `Timer` in an attempt to prevent any possible issues when you change the `text` value

Comment: Haha, I understand what your saying but have absolutely no clue how to do that sorry...

Comment: Well, how do you think you would do it?  Start with an idea and see if you can the functionality you need. If you have problems, ask and I'll/we'll see if we can over some direction ;)

Comment: I'm trying to implement what you said into a custom method but it returns:

The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined.

Basically im trying to do this:

Comment: public void slowPrint(String text) {
    // Timer stuff here
}

Which gives me the error...

Comment: Make sure you `import javax.swing.Timer` and not `java.util.Timer` ;)

Comment: Yes I did that, then it shows the error... I will add an update on what I'm trying to do...

Comment: The "undefined constructor" error or something else?

Comment: Exactly as stated in Eclipse:

The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: Also Make sure you're importing `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` and not `javafx.event.ActionEvent`

Comment: Hmmm.... Funnily enough, Eclipse didn't even get to the point of importing ActionEvent... It just threw the error as I imported Timer...

Even with ActionEvent imported it actually doesn't change anything...

Also, would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: I would, but you don't have enough rep ;)

Comment: Are you able to add the entire class file to the question?

Comment: Once I add `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;` it works fine for me (or at least, that's no where I get errors).  Eclipse might have be looking at a cached view.  Have you tried a clean and build?

Comment: Ahh! Not your fault, you just wrote ActionEvent which done absolutely nothing. Haha! Thanks, ill continue to try and get back to you...

Comment: It's a class instance field (declared at the top of `TestPane` in my example)

Comment: Oops, hope you didn't read that index one, found it.

Now, ANOTHER problem.
Nothing has errors except for the timer.stop(); inside the else statement. It returns the error: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable timer defined in an enclosing scope.....

And if I try to add final to Timer it says it may not of been initialized...

Comment: Okay, trying using `((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();` instead ;) (inside the `ActionListener`)

Comment: Thanks alot MadProgrammer. Not only are you great in this area but you have the patience to cope with a semi-beginner. Thanks so much! I will update the question with code so people can use it in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Since I had (most) of the code, I did a simple example for you to compare with your own work.

Comment: No. You basically did all. :D All I was trying to do was, I'm making a custom sort of GUI by undecorating the frame, putting my own title bar on it and making a Mac Terminal sort of program where the user writes something, it comes back normally, but the output (example the output of writing "help") will be slow printed...

Comment: You "could" slow print everything with this version, but that's up to you ;)

Comment: Yes, thats what I saw. Thanks again dude.
I really appreciate it.